why grpc java thread is blocked without any lock or synchronization syntax around the blocked line
At application startup, I've noticed an extreme delay in the initialization of my gRPC client stream. Through thorough examination via logs and jstack, I've identified that the 'grpc-default-executor-{x}' thread is exhibiting significant sluggishness. I've conducted periodic thread dumps using jstack at intervals of 0.1s, and below are some noteworthy lines extracted from the thread dump logs:
thread_dump_27.log:
2024-05-24 17:44:35
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):
...
"grpc-default-executor-1" #246 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd6e803c000 nid=0x6427 runnable [0x00007fd6bf960000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.find(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findNative(ClassLoader.java:1963)
        - locked <0x00000006c0065c20> (a java.util.Vector)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:114)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.connectInternal(DatagramSocket.java:152)
        - locked <0x000000078c4fdd40> (a java.net.DatagramSocket)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.connect(DatagramSocket.java:458)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:400)
        - locked <0x000000078c4fdd40> (a java.net.DatagramSocket)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:208)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(DnsContext.java:434)


...

"grpc-default-executor-0" #245 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd768037000 nid=0x6422 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fd6bfe65000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findNative(ClassLoader.java:1960)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000006c0065c20> (a java.util.Vector)
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:114)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.connectInternal(DatagramSocket.java:152)
        - locked <0x0000000788977f00> (a java.net.DatagramSocket)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.connect(DatagramSocket.java:458)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:400)
        - locked <0x0000000788977f00> (a java.net.DatagramSocket)
        at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:208

thread_dump_28.log
2024-05-24 17:44:36
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):
...
"grpc-default-executor-1" #246 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd6e803c000 nid=0x6427 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fd6bf961000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.newClientTransport(NettyChannelBuilder.java:727)
        at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:58)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:254)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:201)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1878)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

...
"grpc-default-executor-0" #245 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd768037000 nid=0x6422 runnable [0x00007fd6bfe5e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.URL.toExternalForm(URL.java:929)
        at java.net.URL.toString(URL.java:915)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.isUrlInJarFile(Handler.java:94)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:80)
        at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:705)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:215)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:569)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:567)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findResource(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1096)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:232)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.dynamic.ClassFileLocator$ForClassLoader.locate(ClassFileLocator.java:438)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.dynamic.ClassFileLocator$ForClassLoader.locate(ClassFileLocator.java:419)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.dynamic.ClassFileLocator$Compound.locate(ClassFileLocator.java:1933)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default.doDescribe(TypePool.java:665)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution.access$001(TypePool.java:747)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution.doResolve(TypePool.java:845)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.pool.TypePool$Default$WithLazyResolution$LazyTypeDescription.delegate(TypePool.java:914)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase$OfSimpleType$WithDelegation.getInterfaces(TypeDescription.java:8056)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$OfNonGenericType.getInterfaces(TypeDescription.java:3654)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$Generic$LazyProjection$WithEagerNavigation.getInterfaces(TypeDescription.java:6393)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.matcher.HasSuperTypeMatcher.matches(HasSuperTypeMatcher.java:66)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.matcher.HasSuperTypeMatcher.matches(HasSuperTypeMatcher.java:31)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher$Junction$Conjunction.matches(ElementMatcher.java:122)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.skywalking.apm.dependencies.net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder$Default$ExecutingTransformer.transform(AgentBuilder.java:10186)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        - locked <0x00000007a78eebe8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.newClientTransport(NettyChannelBuilder.java:727)
        at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:58)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:254)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:201)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1878)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)

thread_dump_29.log:
2024-05-24 17:44:37
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):
...
"grpc-default-executor-1" #246 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd6e803c000 nid=0x6427 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd6bf961000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport.start(NettyClientTransport.java:217)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:259)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:201)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1878)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x000000077bcf1750> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

...

"grpc-default-executor-0" #245 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd768037000 nid=0x6422 runnable [0x00007fd6bfe65000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.<clinit>(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:71)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport.start(NettyClientTransport.java:217)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:259)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:201)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1878)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x000000077c398b10> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)


thread_dump_30.log:
2024-05-24 17:44:39
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode):
...
"grpc-default-executor-1" #246 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd6e803c000 nid=0x6427 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd6bf961000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport.start(NettyClientTransport.java:217)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.start(ForwardingConnectionClientTransport.java:34)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:259)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.access$400(InternalSubchannel.java:66)
        at io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel$2.run(InternalSubchannel.java:201)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
        at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1878)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000007bbb850a0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

I am wondering

Why #246 thread is blocked in thread_dump_28.log: while there is no any lock or synchronization syntax around that line https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/3500243f4320fcde1d567184b822c98de017498e/netty/src/main/java/io/grpc/netty/NettyChannelBuilder.java#L727



Why #246 thread is runnable in thread_dump_29.log and thread_dump_30.log while no even one single line has been executed i.e. The stack head is the same line.


It could be that one of argument expressions is calling a synchronized method and the thread is blocking while acquiring the lock on on the target for the call.

Based on the commit hash provided, you are using grpc-java 1.46, which is quite old (the most recent one is 1.64). Please upgrade to a recent version and see if the issue doesn't occur.
